# Cancelling flight booked by travel agent

Tags: air-travel, cancellations, united-airlines, travel-agency

My wife and I booked an international trip through a travel agency, with the flight on United/Lufthansa. Due to Covid, we have pushed our travel to July 2022. The problem is that United is currently requiring rebooked trips to be taken by end of March 2022.

So, we asked our travel agent if we could just use the United credit for other domestic travel we have planned. She said we can only use that credit to travel to places that the agency books trips for, which does not include any domestic locations. I have the confirmation number for our flights and when I enter the number on United's website I have the option to cancel/change the flight. Is there anything preventing me from skirting the agency and canceling the flights myself? Or since the flight was booked by the agency, am I stuck with their rules?

Comment: You can call the airlines directly and confirm. I had an UIA flight and it was cancelled last year due to Covid. The travel agency wasn't doing anything to get me the refund. I contacted the airlines directly and they issues me a voucher with original cost + 25% extra value for any UIA flight until April 2022.